# How to remove [] when writing a list to file?

Tags: python

I would like to seek some help with the writing of a dictionary to file.

My current dictionary structure is:

> {'A': ['123', '123, '123', '123']}

How can I write out my dictionary to a text file without the square brackets etc?

> A, 123 123 123 123 123

For reference, my current print out to a text is in this format:

> A, [123, 123, 123, 123, 123]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Jensenlwt, take the [tour] if you haven't yet. You show "your current print out", can you show the code that produces it?

Comment: @Blckknght Hi Blckknght, thanks for the recommendation! It's a code for my assignment hence I didn't included it in any case for conflict with my school. But I did received some helpful replies in the following comments. Will follow the guidelines the next time round on less sensitive questions!

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few options to consider:

(1) Print each row independently (what you have done but the list is being treated as an object):

```
In [6]: for key, value in my_dict.items():
   ...:     print(key, value)

A ['123', '123', '123', '123']
```

(2) Pass each item in the list to the print function (note the `*`) and so we no longer treat the list as an object but notice now that the default separator between arguments in the print function is just a space (so now get no commas):

```
In [7]: for key, value in my_dict.items():
   ...:     print(key, *value)

A 123 123 123 123
```

(3) Add the commas to separate the items in the print:

```
In [8]: for key, value in my_dict.items():
   ...:     print(key, *value, sep=",")

A,123,123,123,123
```

(4) Use the string `join` method:

```
In [9]: for key, value in my_dict.items():
   ...:     print(key, ",".join(value))

A 123,123,123,123
```

Comment: This would be useful! Will try it out with the various options. Thanks a lot @nick

Answer (score 0):

This code should do the trick

```
for key, value in mydictionary.items():
      output_string = ','.join([str(key), ' '.join([str(i) for i in value])])
      #your write code goes here
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Arun! Would try this method as well. Appreciate for the help!